# Squid Proxy doesn't work when running as Docker Container

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, proxy, dockerfile, squid

I am able to block sites fine when I install squid proxy onto my Ec2 and proxy with the EC2 IP address and default port. When I dockerized the process I can no longer deny any sites even with `https_access deny all` . Is there something special I am missing form my `squid.conf` or perhaps my dockerfile? I see all traffic go through my `access.log` but I am unable to block anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask about squid configuration.

Comment: sure thing my apologies